# VB6: array of controls field, checking if it is numeric

Tags: arrays, vb6, controls, numeric

I’m new to Visual Basic 6, so please be patient (and thorough with your answers).

I’m building a form and I need to check if the information entered in one of its fields is numeric, otherwise the program has to beep.

The field is part of an array of controls and it is named txtMyField(0)

Last thing in my code I’ve written:

```
Private Sub txtMyField_Change(Index As Integer)
If Not IsNumeric(txtMyField(0).Text) Then
    Beep
End If
End Sub
```

I don’t know if this code is correct and I don’t how to call the Sub to use it in order to check the field’s value before inserting in database.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the Validate event.  You need to ensure that the CausesValidation property is true, if it is then the Validate event will be raised for that control.

Your event might look something like this:

```
Private Sub txtMyField_Validate(Index As Integer, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(txtMyField(Index).Text) Then
        Beep
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This would ensure that all the controls in your control array are numeric (given that their CausesValidation property is set to True at startup).  If one of the controls is empty or contains non-numeric characters you will get a Beep when the control loses focus.

Note some things here

- Sounding a Beep is not really a good way to indicate a validation error.  A messagebox or textbox in the form to display the error is usually a better way.  The user may not hear your beep or may not understand that "a beep" means "you need to provide a number in this field".
- Your code referenced control with index = 0.  The event may fire for any of the controls in the control array, so checking the value of control(0) is not really a logical thing to do when you should be validating control(5) (for example).

Answer (score 1):

instead of beeping you could also make your texbox only accept certain keys

for example a textbox which will only accept numeric keys and the backspace key :

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  KeyAscii = NrOnly(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Function NrOnly(intKey As Integer)
  Dim intReturn As Integer
  intReturn = intKey
  Select Case intKey
    Case vbKeyBack
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
    Case Else
      intReturn = 0
  End Select
  NrOnly = intReturn
End Function
```

you can add more intelligence to the NrOnly function to allow more keys, or check for certain boundaries

be careful though as the user can still use the mouse to input other data via copy&paste

Comment: Don't forget to still handle the `Change` event to catch text being pasted.